# horizontal menu with auto width and same dimension of the tabs

Tags: css, css-float

I'd like to create a horizontal menu with auto(100%) width.

MY CSS

```
.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
}

.horizontal ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}

.horizontal li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.horizontal li a {
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

MY HTML

```
<div class="horizontal">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Long Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Short Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Really Long Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Other Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that I would like that the "tabs" (a elements) have the same size maintaining 100% of width

It would be possible to do so? How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: do you want these elements to span the whole width of the parent element or just be a fixed width each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give li width in percentage.

```
.horizontal li {
  display: table-cell;
  width:20%; // because you have 5 anchors.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply adding something like this:

`li{width:400px;}`

If you have or will have more `li`'s on the page, you can either give them a class, give the `ul` a class and use:

`ul.header > li{width:400px;}`

or just use:

`.horizontal > ul > li{width:400px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are searching for the following, but u can try the following:

```
.horizontal ul {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: justify;
  background: #222;
}

.horizontal ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```