# Equal Horizontal Menu in CSS (Legacy Support)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to build an equal horizontal menu in CSS which is still supported in older browsers like IE9. (Yes, I know....)

Been testing in FF and Chrome with newer CSS3 techniques and working excellent! Tried in IE9, as we still need to support it.... and failed.

I searched around, and found some of these links which did the trick...

http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/

[horizontal menu with auto width and same dimension of the tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357944/horizontal-menu-with-auto-width-and-same-dimension-of-the-tabs)

...However if the number of menu items change you need to either change you CSS or cater for X number of menu items with multiple declarations...

Is there a simple one case covers all that will support IE9 and still be compatible with newer browsers without affecting them? (ie: special stylesheet for IE9)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you could make use of `display: table` and `display: cell`, as in:

```css
.menu {
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Option 1</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Option 2</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Option 3</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Option 4</li>
</ul>
```